# How to stretch the buttons so that they fit the entire frame?

Tags: python, tkinter, button

```
import tkinter as tk

window = tk.Tk()

for i in range(3):
    
    for j in range(3):
        window.columnconfigure(i,weight = 1, minsize=50)
        window.rowconfigure(j,weight = 1, minsize = 50)
        frame = tk.Frame(relief=tk.RAISED, borderwidth=3, padx=5, pady=5)
        frame.grid(row=i, column=j,sticky = "nsew")
        but = tk.Button(text=f"row {i+1}\n column {j+1}", master = frame)
        but.grid(row=0, column=0,sticky = "nsew")
window.mainloop()
```

even if I put `sticky="nsew"` for the button, it does not stretch.

Comment: That's because there's padding. Remove the padding (`padx` and `pady`) on the frame.

Answer (score 0):

> How to stretch the buttons so that they fit the entire frame?

The easier way to do it is to replace `but.grid()` with `but.pack()` layout manager.

On line 13, change this:

```
but.grid(row=0, column=0,sticky = "nsew")
```

to:

```
but.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Screenshot when resizing:

[image]